# Do private ivars in Objective-C have atomic attribute by default (like properties)?

Tags: objective-c, properties

Consider a scenario where I have some instance variable like this.

```
@implementation Foo {
    NSString *foo;
}

// Some code 

@end
```

I wanted to know if this foo ivar would be atomic by default? Does it behave similar to a property (had I) created in the @interface of this class?

Can someone enlighten me as to what are the default attributes of an ivar created in such a manner?

Comment: By default, ivars are strong, readwrite, nonatomic. You can't change the latter two. They are features of Objective-C ivars. You can only modify the memory management of a pointer from strong to weak using the `__weak` modifier.

Comment: Very strong coding convention is that instance variables should start with an underscore. So make it _foo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I wanted to know if this foo ivar would be atomic by default

No, it would not. That is one of the (many) reasons for using a `@property` declaration instead of an ivar. With a `@property` declaration, you get an actual *accessor method* written for you behind the scenes, and this will be atomic by default.

Comment: Not exactly a reason to use a property, since making a property atomic is in most cases useless.

Comment: Properties provide control. Bare ivars don't. Use properties. Now that we have autosynthesis and ARC, it costs you nothing.

Comment: I wouldn't say "no", because there cannot be a concept of atomicity to a (C-) object, but only to control flows including accesses. Therefore one should "unask" the Q.