# Atomicity of Class-Level Static Variables

Tags: objective-c, static-variables, atomic

I am working with an Objective-C class which contains a static variable that can be stored, retrieved, or deallocated at any time:

User.h

```
@interface User : NSObject

/// Returns the current user if set, nil if not
+ (User * _Nullable)currentUser;

/// Sets the current user
+ (void)setCurrentUser:(NSString * _Nonnull)name;

/// Removes the current user
+ (void)removeCurrentUser;

// Getters

/// Returns the user's name if set, nil if there is no user set
@property (nullable, nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSString *name;

@end
```

User.m

```
@interface User ()

@property (nullable, nonatomic, strong, readwrite) NSString *name;

@end

@implementation User

#pragma mark - Static Variables

static User *currentUser;

#pragma mark - Static Object Setters and Getters

+ (User *)currentUser
{
    return currentUser;
}

+ (void)setCurrentUser:(NSString * _Nonnull)name
{
    currentUser = [[User alloc] initWithName:name];
}

+ (void)removeCurrentUser
{
    currentUser = nil;
}

#pragma mark - init

- (instancetype)initWithName:(NSString * _Nonnull)name
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _name = name;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

My question is on the atomicity of this static class-level variable. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36985370/2415822) states that ivars are `strong, readwrite, nonatomic` by default, and the atomicity is defined by the getter and setter. Does this also apply to static variables? Is `currentUser` nonatomic by default? To make `currentUser` atomic would I have to wrap my getter and setter in `@synchronized(self) { ... }` blocks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All variables are non-atomic.

When a property is declared atomic, the synthesized code for the setter and getter includes extra code to make the variable's access atomic.

With plain old variables, there is no auto synthesis of any code to make them atomic. If you need a variable to be atomic, you need to add your own code to make its access atomic.

Using `@synchronized` is one option. But for a `static` variable, using `@synchronized(self)` won't work because multiple instances of the class can access a `static` variable and `@synchronized(self)` will only ensure no two threads from the same instance will access the static but it won't prevent another instance on another thread from also accessing the `static` variable.

One solution for the `static` would be to use `@synchronized([self class])`.

Another solution for the case in your question is to get rid of the `static` variable and setup the class with a singleton. Then the singleton could track the current user.

Comment: Would `@synchronized(self)` work from within a class method rather than an instance method (since there, `self` basically refers to the `Class` rather than the instance)?

Comment: @NSGod That would work in a class method and combined with using `@synchronized([self class])` in instance methods, all access would be synchronized from any class/instance method. There is one case this fails on and that is if there are any C functions in the .m file that also access the `static` variable.

Comment: It also fails if there are subclasses. If `+currentUser` is called on both this class and its subclass, then `self` will be two different things and the accesses won't be synchronized. Safest would be `@synchronized([User class])` or an explicit lock.

Comment: @KenThomases Good point. `[self class]` will be different between the class and a subclass.